# Calculate text size before inserted to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Is this possible to calculate height of the text BEFORE it is inserted into DOM?
Width of the div container is known, but I need a way to calculate its height before it is inserted.
The heights of the one line of text is also known (css), so the height could be calculated by multiplying the height of one line by the amount of lines, but the question is if this is possible to calculated BEFORE it's DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question explicitly requires the text not to be inserted into the dom this precludes the usually used method of simply inserting it outside the viewport and then measuring there.

An alternative approach: The canvas 2D rendering context's [measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) function which can be used to determine the width if you know which styling (font width) will apply in advance.

Some advanced CSS rules such as `letter-spacing` may make those results inaccurate.